# Como configurar Nginx para que redirecione a un archivo index en cualquier directorio del servidor web

Tags: docker, nginx

Hola soy novato en el uso de nginx, deseo tener muchas api en el mismo servidor web, he podido hacer que funcione una sola api, pero si me cambio de directorio (ruta) a otra me lanza el error de no encontrado.

Lo que necesito es consumir los servicios de la siguiente manera:

http://mis-servicios/mi-api/miruta

http://mis-servicios/mi-api-2/miruta

http://mis-servicios/mi-api-3/mruta

http://mis-servicios/mi-api-n/miruta

cada api tiene un nombre distinto y se encuentra en directorios distintos pero al mismo nivel del directorio root, he tratado con varias configuraciones con la directiva location, pero no he podido lograr que funcionen todas, solo una.

No me gustaria tener un location por cada api, me gustaria configurarlo de tal forma que si ingreso a cualquier directorio siempre me redireccione al index de ese directorio, más no sé si es posible configurarlo de esa manera.

Tengo un archivo de configuración el cual se los muestro

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/my-api;
    index index.php index.htm index.html;
    server_name backend_server;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /index.php {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout     300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout        300s;
        fastcgi_buffers             256 4k;   
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass                php_container:9000;
        uwsgi_read_timeout      300s;

    }


}
```

Comment: cada subdirectorio tiene un index.php ? O tienes uno solo en la raíz haciendo de router para las tres apis? Dentro de cada subdirectorio hay otros archivos PHP o tienes los controllers en otro lado no accesible directamente?

Comment: otra pregunta. Tu dominio se llama backend_server o mis-servicios?

Comment: hola, creo que no me explique bien, tengo varias apis en el directorio raiz, cada una con su respectivo nombre que es el directorio donde se encuentra, mi directorio raiz  tiene algo como html/api1/index.php, html/api2/index.php, html/api3/index.php, html/api4/index.php y asi con todos mis proyectos, cada uno es una api, no es que en todos los subdirectorios de cada proyecto necesiten el index, lo que quiero es simple, configurar nginx para poder consumir todas mis apis. Por el momento solo puedo consumir una sola y no se como configurar mi location para poder consumir todas.

Comment: sobre la otra pregunta, el nombre del dominio si es backend_server, el nombre que puse para ejemplificar "mis-servicios" solo era ilustrativo para tratar de darme a entender

Comment: Ok pero en el directorio común, existe index.php?

Comment: si, en todas mis apis existe un index.php y en la raiz tmb, aunque este no haga nada

Comment: Pero estas mandando a todos a ese index, dentro de location / el try files se va a mis-servicios/index.php. tienes que mandarlos a su ruta relativa con una exp regular (estoy en el móvil por eso no me extiendo)

Comment: Entiendo lo que me comentas, podrias ayudarme un poco con la expresion regular que funcionaria para todas mis apis en mi sitio..

Comment: sigo sin poder configurar esto, alguna idea, saludos

Answer (score 0):

El archivo `index.html` (o el que `index.*`) **debe existir** en cada directorio. Si no existe, se lista el directorio. Puedes desactivar esta característica con la opción `autoindex off`. Consulta la [documentación](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html).

Comment: todos los directorios de mis api tienen un archivo index, pero al solicitar la dirección simplemente mi servicio no es llamado, además el mensaje arrojado es archivo no encontrado y no me lista ninguna lista de archivos del directorio